# Speed limits for drivers with less than two years experience in Germany and Poland?

Tags: germany, driving, driving-licenses, poland

I am from the Republic of Belarus and in our country there is a speed limit on the motorway for new drivers is 70 km/hr, while for drivers with more than 2 years' experience it is 110 km/hr.

I am asking this question because I am going to travel with my friends (2 drivers including me) to Italy by car via Poland and Germany this summer. By the date of the trip my driving experience will be 10 months.

Are there any special speed limits in Europe (specifically Germany and Poland) for drivers with little experience? I tried finding this information on my own and found 100 km/hr for Italy, but nothing for Germany and Poland.

Comment: Do you mind if we change the title to specify only Poland and Germany?

Comment: It will be okay. Thank you for your attention.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are no experience-related difference to speed limits in Germany (where I live), and neither are there in Poland, according to [all sources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_limits_in_Poland) [I've looked at](http://superjazda.blogspot.de/p/safe-driving-in-poland-for-foreign.html). I think the Belarusian regulation is rather unusual.

Comment: Not that unusual, as the OP said there are similar regulations in Italy and I know it's also the case in France.

Comment: In Germany, there are also other restrictions for new drivers. For drivers with less than two years of experience, the legal blood alcohol content is e.g. 0% instead of 0.05% for other drivers. The consequences for breaking most other rules are also much more severe for new drivers.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo but only if you have a german driving license or you are living in Germany. If you're just a tourist there are no restrictions for new drivers

Comment: @Dirty-flow: That's not entirely correct. The lower legal BAC level is e.g. also applicable for drivers below the age of 21, also if they don't have a German driver's licence or are living in Germany.

Comment: Good answer, there is no such speed limits in Poland.